# Solving Trignometric Transcedental equations in Matlab

Tags: trigonometry, matlab

I need a little help solving these eqns using Matlab. `phir` and `delr` values are required. `alpha` and `psi` are constants.

```
[phir,delr]=solve(tan(2*phir)*cos(delr)-tan(2*alpha) , sin(2*phir)*sin(delr)-sin(2*psi));
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should probably start by setting the equations equal to something. Also, you should specify what toolboxes you're using. Symbolic computation is not a default feature of MATLAB.

Comment: tan(2*phir)*cos(delr)=tan(2*alpha) alpha being a known constant psi is also known

Comment: any other way to solve the eqns in matlab? maybe finding the solution using trial and error?

Comment: There aren't any equations in your post. Also, consider using latex to format the equations. It makes it much easier to read and increases your chances of getting help.

Comment: The two equations are:

// tan(2*alpha)=tan(2*phir)*cos(delr)// 
// sin(2*psi)=sin(2*phir)*sin(delr)//

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have two methods of solving equations: symbolically and numerically. If you're going to solve numerically, you need to know whether your equations are linear or nonlinear (yours are nonlinear). Next, you need to determine if their gradient is well-defined and/or easy to compute. Depending on the algorithm, you might need to compute the gradient by hand. If this is too difficult, there are a bevy of options for handling this difficulty. However, I do not intend to present a treatise on numerical analysis.

---

The MATLAB command `solve` is part of the symbolic toolbox. Since you have not presented any other code, I do not know whether you have properly set up a symbolic solution, and since I think the symbolic toolbox, ultimately, is a waste, I will ignore it.

Instead, you have the system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}\tan 2\phi_r \cos \delta_r &= \tan 2\alpha, \\
\sin 2\phi_r \sin\delta_r &= \sin 2\psi\end{align*}.$$ I presume $\alpha$ is a constant.

Define functions $$\begin{align*} \mathbf{f}(\phi_r,\delta_r) &\stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} \begin{pmatrix} f_1\left(\phi_r,\delta_r\right), \\ f_2\left(\phi_r,\delta_r\right)\end{pmatrix} \\
f_1(\phi_r,\delta_r) &\stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} \tan 2\phi_r \cos \delta_r - \tan 2\alpha, \\
f_2(\phi_r,\delta_r) &\stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} \sin 2\phi_r \sin \delta_r - \sin 2\psi, 
\end{align*}$$
and your system becomes

$$\mathbf{f}(\phi_r,\delta_r) = \mathbf{0}.$$

Using the Optimization Toolbox, we can use the `fsolve` command to solve equations of this form, provide we have an initial guess. Let this initial guess be $\mathbf{x}_0 = \begin{pmatrix} \phi_{r_0} \\ \delta_{r_0}\end{pmatrix}$.

Our code would then be:

```
alpha = some constant value;
psi = some other constant value;
two_alpha = 2*alpha;
two_psi = 2*psi;
phi_r0 = some guess;
delta_r0 = some other guess;
x0 = [phi_r0; delta_r0]; % x(1) is phi_r, x(2) is delta_r
f = @(x)[tan(2*x(1))*cos(x(2))-tan(two_alpha); sin(2*x(1))*sin(x(2))-sin(two_psi);
[x,fval] = fsolve(f,x0);
```

Picking the initial guesses for $\phi_r$ and $\delta_r$ is left to you.

Comment: Thanks Arkamis. I found the solution by hand and used this in the program. The code you provided seemed to result in an error.

Comment: What was the error? Do you have the Optimization toolbox installed?

Comment: No. It seems to run properly. My bad.